# How is this program working behind the scenes?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

```
from tkinter import *

def b1_print(value):
    print(value)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x420")



for digit in range(1,11):
    b1 = Button(root, text="Print", command=lambda x=digit: b1_print(x))
    b1.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

So, When I run this program. It creates 10 Buttons named "print", when I press the first Button it prints 1 and when I press the second Button it prints 2, when I press the third Button it prints 3 and so on. But how is this working behind the scenes.

I am a newbie, so, can anyone give an explanation that a intermediate programmer understands. Please! Please! Please!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating inside the loop 10 new functions, without names (because they are anonymous functions).

Each of these functions does one thing, print its default parameter, and its default parameter is digit.

For example:

In the first iteration, a function is created, with a default parameter called "x" that has the value of 1, this function prints "x".

In the second iteration, another function is created, with a default parameter called "x" that has the value of 2, this function prints "x".

And so.

I hope I have explained myself correctly.

Comment: Thank you very veryveryveryvery very very very much :)